# Re-organizing Access table (convert rows to columns)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a database where there are 2 fields similar (that match another table) and then the third is unique.  I want to convert the table to have the 3rd unique value listed in columns instead of a separate record.

I.E.

```
5/1/2013  A321  1  $1,120
5/2/2013  A325  1  $2,261
5/1/2013  A321  2  $2,120
```

will convert to

```
5/1/2013  A321  $1,120  $2,120
5/2/2013  A325  $2,261
```

I could create separate queries for each value in column 3 and then have another query that joins them in the fashion I want them to but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For test data in [OldTable]

```
FieldA      FieldB  FieldC  FieldD
----------  ------  ------  ------
2013-05-01  A321         1    1120
2013-05-02  A325         1    2261
2013-05-01  A321         2    2120
```

the Crosstab Query

```sql
TRANSFORM First(FieldD) AS FirstOfFieldD
SELECT FieldA, FieldB
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            FieldA,
            FieldB,
            'Value' & FieldC AS ColumnName,
            FieldD
        FROM OldTable
    )
GROUP BY FieldA, FieldB
PIVOT ColumnName
```

returns

```
FieldA      FieldB  Value1  Value2
----------  ------  ------  ------
2013-05-01  A321      1120    2120
2013-05-02  A325      2261
```

If you want to actually create a new table containing those results then save the above query in Access as [xtabQuery] and then run

```sql
SELECT xtabQuery.* INTO NewTable
FROM xtabQuery;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would open up the Query Wizard and create a Crosstab Query.  It should prompt you to put in what you want for the columns and records.

When the query has been written by the Wizard, just make that into a MakeTable query by opening it in SQL View and adding "INTO MyNewTable" before the FROM statement.