# Cross-Tab Query or other option?

Tags: ms-access

I'm not sure if a cross-tab query is the ideal way to do this, I haven't been able to make it work.

I have a table of contact information from all customers, formatted as follows (with sample data):

```
Customer # | Contact Name | Telephone Number | E-mail Address
-----------+--------------+------------------+---------------
32         | John         | 123-123-1234     | test@test.com
32         | Deb          | 123-211-6547     | deb@test.com            
71         |              |                  |
76         |              |                  |
123        |              |                  |
```

How can I create a query that will take all contacts for each facility and put them on one line? So it would have:

```
Contact Name---Telephone---E-mail---Contact Name---Telephone---Email---etc.
```

Comment: Have to ask - why? This might be possible with a sequence of queries but won't be simple. Could use VBA and write data to a 'temp' table - table is permanent but data is temporary. What is the maximum number of contacts for a single facility/customer? Or maybe use Allen Browne's ConcatRelated function http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform multiple rows into columns with unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898593/transform-multiple-rows-into-columns-with-unique-key)

Comment: Just follow the pattern in the other answer to add an additional column.  Perhaps the most confusing part might be generating correct sequential numbers which dictate the horizontal sort order.  Perhaps by name and email: `1 + DCount("[Customer #]","TableName","[Customer #]=" & [Customer #] & " and [Contact Name]<'" & Replace([Contact Name],"'","''") & "' and [E-mail Address]<'" & Replace([E-mail Address],"'","''") & "'") AS SeqNum`.  Heed the warning about Null values in whatever fields you use to define this sequential number.