# Multiple records represented as columns in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

in Access I have two tables, tblID where with a field fName and tblDiagnoses and field fDgCode. Each fName can have multiple fDgCodes, which are unique.
If I make a query I get a result like this

```
Mike ...  222
Mike ...  344
Mike ...  345
John ...  234
Peter ... 210
Peter ... 222
```

How could I get this in one line, each entry in the second table as a separate column in my query or excel table-

```
A         B   C   D
Mike ... 222 344 345
John ... 234
Peter .. 210 222
```

Comment: thanks, I'll check that, I didn't really know what words to use for searh

Comment: No worries. That's why we are here! :)

Comment: Let me add a subplot. All the values in second field are unique, and I'd like the values for each entry be in first n columns . I could select the recordset and put the values in an array with a loop, but I'm not sure how to put them in a query.

Comment: Could you update the question and add sample data that shows that and your desired output for that sample data. That does sound like it's a bit muddier than a simple pivot.

Comment: I hope it's clearer and thanks for your help.

Comment: Where does the `B`, `C`, `D` come from here?

Comment: Newly formed columns at the end of the query. I'm starting to think this might be easier to do through vba, creating a new table, copy most of the values from other tables and populate my new columns cycling trough that one table and adding columns as needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform multiple rows into columns with unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898593/transform-multiple-rows-into-columns-with-unique-key)

Answer (score 0):

A CROSSTAB with DCount() can accomplish that output. Be aware that performance can be slow with large dataset. Assumes fDgCode is number type and no duplicate codes for each name.

```
TRANSFORM First(tblDiagnoses.fDgCode) AS FirstCode
SELECT tblDiagnoses.fName
FROM tblDiagnoses
GROUP BY tblDiagnoses.fName
PIVOT DCount("*","tblDiagnoses","fName='" & [fName] & "' AND fDgCode<" & [fDgCode])+1;
```